# How to specify dict type in numba njit decorator and timeit not reusing compiled version

Tags: python, performance, numpy, types, numba

I have written a program which groups entries in target numpy array together using the indices mentioned in indices numpy array and returns as dictionary with key as index and value as all entries having same index. For performance reasons I like to use numba and has clear advantage over other python methods

I would like to enter types in njit decorator for eager compilation.
I understand that numba can do type inferencing.

```py
import numpy as np
import numba as nb
import random
import timeit


# uncomment njit argument to see error
@nb.njit#((nb.int64[:], nb.int64[:], nb.types.DictType[nb.int64, nb.int64[:]]))
def sort5(des, indices, d):
    present_indices = np.unique(indices)
    for i in nb.prange(present_indices.shape[0]):
        d[i] = des[indices==present_indices[i]]
    return d

indices = np.array([random.randint(0,9) for i in range(3500)])
des = np.array([i for i in range(len(indices))])
d = nb.typed.Dict.empty(
    key_type=nb.types.int64,
    value_type=nb.types.int64[:],
)

# Compiling but does not reuse for 9999 runs I think
print("sort5", timeit.timeit(lambda: sort5(des, indices, d), number=10000))
indices = np.array([random.randint(0,9) for i in range(3500)])
des = np.array([i for i in range(len(indices))])

# But only this timeit seems to use compiled version from previous timeit for all 10000 runs
print("sort5", timeit.timeit(lambda: sort5(des, indices, d), number=10000))
```

**1: What should I put the type of dict in njit decorator**

**What I tried**

```py
# Trying to get type instance
nb.typeof(d)
# DictType[int64,array(int64, 1d, A)]<iv=None>
```

From above I try to replace with `@nb.njit((nb.int64[:], nb.int64[:], nb.types.DictType[nb.int64, nb.int64[:]]))`. I also try with `nb.typed.Dict[nb.int64, nb.int64[:]]` but i get similar error but with `ABCMeta` class

```
TypeError: '_TypeMetaclass' object is not subscriptable
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-98e6f766338f> in <module>
      3 import random
      4 import timeit
----> 5 @nb.njit((nb.int64[:], nb.int64[:], nb.types.DictType[nb.int64, nb.int64[:]]))
      6 def sort5(des, indices, d):
      7     present_indices = np.unique(indices)

TypeError: '_TypeMetaclass' object is not subscriptable
```

I believe I am missing something trivial here but not sure

**2: Why second timeit is faster**

Also if you see output of program, the second timeit is using compiled version but not the first, as second timeit finishes in 1.17s while first take 2.66

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have your brackets wrong

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb
import random
import timeit


@nb.njit([(nb.int64[:], nb.int64[:], nb.types.DictType(nb.int64, nb.int64[:]))])
def sort5(des, indices, d):
    present_indices = np.unique(indices)
    for i in nb.prange(present_indices.shape[0]):
        d[i] = des[indices==present_indices[i]]
    return d

indices = np.array([random.randint(0,9) for i in range(3500)])
des = np.array([i for i in range(len(indices))])
d = nb.typed.Dict.empty(
    key_type=nb.types.int64,
    value_type=nb.types.int64[:],
)

# Compiling but does not reuse for 9999 runs I think
print("sort5", timeit.timeit(lambda: sort5(des, indices, d), number=10000))
indices = np.array([random.randint(0,9) for i in range(3500)])
des = np.array([i for i in range(len(indices))])

# But only this timeit seems to use compiled version from previous timeit for all 10000 runs
print("sort5", timeit.timeit(lambda: sort5(des, indices, d), number=10000))
```

gives me

```
sort5 1.8259385739999914
sort5 1.9655513189999994
```

So I guess it also resolved the speed problem of your 2nd question.

And since it helped me solve this. I thought it might be useful to add that I used the following to figure out what types it inferred

```
sort5.overloads.keys()
```

```
odict_keys([(array(int64, 1d, A), array(int64, 1d, A), DictType[int64,array(int64, 1d, A)]<iv=None>)])
```

Comment: Thanks alot, understood about timeit. But I inferred the type using`nb.typeof(d)` as `DictType[int64,array(int64, 1d, A)]<iv=None>`. Thats the reason why I used square brackets. Can you clarify a bit more on the two dictype, like we need to use nb.types.DictType() in njit, but when printing typeof it shows subscripted DictType[]

Comment: @eroot163pi tbh. I don't quite know. I just tryed out DictType with square brackets and it threw me an error.